# Acceder a atributos de un objeto que hace parte de un arreglo de objetos

Tags: java, array, poo, object, nullpointerexception

Hola atodos queridos programadores.
hace poco empece a trabajar con java y estoy aprendiendo el tema de programación orientada a objetos. En este momento estoy trabajando con un programa en el que he definido un arreglo bidimensional de objetos llamado `ArreglosYlistas objetoSillas[][] = new ArreglosYlistas[15][15];`. Posteriormente he realizado dos ciclos for para llenar los atributos de cada objeto, pero a la hora de ejecutar el programa me salta un error de NullPointerException en esta linea del codigo: `objetoSillas[i][x].precio = preferencial;`.
Que me aparece despues de asignar los objetos al espacio correspondiente del arreglo utilizando `objetoSillas[i][x] = new ArreglosYlistas();`en el primer metodo que se ejecuta del programa.
La verdad no se que pueda estar causandolo y me gustaria vuestra ayuda para solucionar el problema, gracias de antemano por tomaros la molestia de ayudarme con mi problema.

Este el es codigo que tengo montado por el momento:

```
import java.awt.Color;


public class ArreglosYlistas{

    //Definicion de atributos de cada silla
    String numSilla;
    float precio; //inicializado en 0.0
    int estado; //inicializado en disponible
    float general, preferencial, palco, segundoPiso;

    //Arreglo tipo objeto para almacenar info de cada silla
    ArreglosYlistas objetoSillas[][] = new ArreglosYlistas[15][15];


    //Metodo para inicializas todas las sillas como disponibles y asignarles el numero de silla
    public void InicializarSillas(){
        String fila = "";
        int contador = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++){
            switch(i){
                case 0:
                    fila = "A0";
                    break;
                case 1:
                    fila = "B";
                    break;    
                case 2:
                    fila = "C";
                    break;    
                case 3:
                    fila = "D";
                    break;    
                case 4:
                    fila = "E";
                    break;    
                case 5:
                    fila = "F";
                    break;
                case 6:
                    fila = "G";
                    break;    
                case 7:
                    fila = "H";
                    break;    
                case 8:
                    fila = "I";
                    break;    
                case 9:
                    fila = "J";
                    break;    
                case 10:
                    fila = "K";
                    break;    
                case 11:
                    fila = "L";
                    break;
                case 12:
                    fila = "M";
                    break;    
                case 13:
                    fila = "N";
                    break;    
                case 14:
                    fila = "O";
                    break;         
            }
            for (int x = 0; x < 15; x++){
                objetoSillas[i][x] = new ArreglosYlistas();
                objetoSillas[i][x].estado = 1;
                objetoSillas[i][x].numSilla = fila + String.valueOf(contador);
                objetoSillas[i][x].precio = 0;
                contador++;
            }
        }
    }

    public float getPrecio(int opc){
        switch(opc){
            case 1:
                return objetoSillas[3][0].precio;
            case 2:
                return objetoSillas[0][0].precio;
            case 3:
                return objetoSillas[5][0].precio;
            case 4:
                return objetoSillas[10][0].precio;
            default:
                return 0;
        }
    }
    //Metodo para asignar precio a cada silla
    public void DefinirPrecio(float _general, float _preferencial, float _palco, float _segundoPiso){
        _general = general;
        _preferencial = preferencial;
        _palco = palco;
        _segundoPiso = segundoPiso;

        //asignar precio a sillas de preferencial
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
            for (int x = 0; x < 15; x++){
                objetoSillas[i][x].precio = preferencial;
            }
        }
        //asignar precio a sillas de general
        for (int i = 3; i < 5; i++){
            for (int x = 0; x < 15; x++){
                objetoSillas[i][x].precio = general;
            }
        }
        for (int i = 5; i < 10; i++){
            for (int x = 2; x < 13; x++){
                objetoSillas[i][x].precio = general;
            }
        }
        //asignar precio a sillas de palco
        for (int i = 5; i < 10; i++){
            for (int x = 0; x < 2; x++){
                objetoSillas[i][x].precio = palco;
            }
            for (int x = 13; x < 15; x++){
                objetoSillas[i][x].precio = palco;
            }
        }
        //asignar precio a sillas de segundo piso
        for (int i = 10; i < 15; i++){
            for (int x = 0; x < 15; x++){
                objetoSillas[i][x].precio = segundoPiso;
            }
        }
    }


    //Metodo para definir color de asiento segun disponibilidad
    public Color colores(int estado){ 
        Color disponible = new Color(0, 204, 0); //1
        Color vendido = new Color(204, 0, 204);  //2
        Color noDisponible = new Color(0, 153, 255);  //3
        switch(estado){
            case 1:
                return disponible;
            case 2:
                return vendido;
            case 3:
                return noDisponible;
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cuando se inicializa un arreglo todos sus espacios están vacíos.

```
objetoSillas[][] = new ArreglosYlistas[15][15];
```

Se tiene que crear un nuevo objeto y asignarlo en esa posición:

```
for (int x = 0; x < 15; x++){

            //crear nuevo objeto y asignarlo en la posición
            objetoSillas[i][x] = new ArreglosYListas();

            objetoSillas[i][x].estado = 1;
            objetoSillas[i][x].numSilla = fila + String.valueOf(contador);
            objetoSillas[i][x].precio = 0;
            contador++;
        }
```

Comment: Gracias, lo he implementado y ya no me marca error. Sin embargo he incluido otro metodo dentro de la misma clase en el que llamo al atributo de un objeto del arreglo en especifico, pero ahora me salta el error NullPointerException en esa linea. La verdad no entiendo el porque. tu podrias explicarme?

Comment: Agrega el código.

Comment: te lo coloco aqui abajo

Comment: En la pregunta para que quede más ordenado

Comment: listo, ya lo edite.

Comment: Llamas al método `InicializarSillas()` antes de los otros métodos?

Comment: Si señor. Es el primer metodo a llamar.

Comment: He probado el siguiente código:  `ArreglosYlistas l = new ArreglosYlistas();
l.InicializarSillas();  l.DefinirPrecio(0, 0, 0, 0);` Y no me da error. Cómo estás llamando los métodos?

Comment: Ya listo, efectivamente era un error al llamar el metodo. Dado que llame a `claseArreglos.InicializarSillas()` pero luego en definir precio lo estoy llamando con otro objeto creado, asi: `claseArreglos2.DefinirPrecio()`. Otra pregunta, dado esto entonces al llamar al metodo inicialzarSillas() con diferentes objetos de la clase creados, se estan formando un arreglo bidimensional por cada uno de ellos, verdad?

Comment: Así es. Cada objeto tiene su propios datos.

Comment: muchas gracias crrlos por la ayuda y por sacar tiempo para analisar mi codigo, y en especial por enseñarme algo nuevo.